# how to find slashes and backslashes in quotes by regex

Tags: regex

how do i find the  string "/" or "\" which is inside of quotes like this:

1

```
"some text some text / some text" more text without qotes / \
```

2

```
"/" more text without qotes / \
```

3

```
"some text some text \ some text" more text without qotes / \
```

4

```
"\" more text without qotes / \
```

output 1: /

output 2: /

output 3: \

output 4: \

**EDIT:**

i tried "\?*([^"]*)/ to find / but it just finds it when it is like "/text" or "text/" but not when it is like "tex/t"

syntax of regex is the one from netbeans search.standard syntax?

Comment: What language are you using, javascript?

Comment: i tried "\?*([^"]*)\/ to find / but i just finds it when it is like "/text" or "text/" but not when it is like "tex/t"

Comment: As @RustyToms said when you have a Regex question you must specify the language you are using

Comment: i just use regex syntax (in netbeans to find all / or \ in quotes to standardize them with File.seperator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe give something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/iXMv5x/2) a try.

It may not be 100% what you're after as I only have a few limited examples to base it off.

The regex is: `^"(?:.*)([\\\/])(?:.*)"(?:.*)$`

And it matches like so:

[image]

Comment: this leads to nothing found

Comment: @user3776738 you're going to have to be more specific with the question then, because as per the link this matches the back and forward slashes.

Comment: hmm it works on regex101.com but not in netbeans, but netbeans doesn't show a syntax error for the regex..mhh

Comment: it works without the circumflex ^  ->       "(?:.*)([\\\/])(?:.*)"(?:.*)$

Comment: @user3776738: It only works in very specific edge cases. In general, it is a very poor solution and [won't work in general](https://regex101.com/r/sEvQK3/2).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, at the time of writing this answer all I had to go on was the 4 test cases given (And not the knowledge that it was going to be run in netbeans/or any other IDE). I would be interested to see what other solutions there are, as well as why this one is so poor (Beyond the fact that it has minimal edge case testing).